# Google Account with SSO not redirecting to IdP as expected

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've been trying to setup SSO with Google Identity as the Service Provider and ADFS as the IdP.

I believe I've got ADFS configured correctly and Cloud Identity at least partially correct, as I can successfully login with ADFS SSO to Google Drive and Google Groups when using the explicit organisation URLs of service.google.com/a/domain.com, so I believe the SAML request/responses are working fine.
I can also determine this is a successful SSO login because I can immediately access the other services as the same user. eg, accessing https://drive.google.com/a/domain.com, going through SSO, then accessing https://console.cloud.google.com works straight away, no further login required.

However when accessing any service directly via its login page(https://accounts.google.com or https://console.cloud.google.com) results in being prompted for a Google username (expected behaviour) and then for a Google password (not expected, as domain.com has 3rd party SSO enabled).

The documentation and [watching the demo this user posted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NpNPizIBIc&feature=youtu.be&t=575) a couple of years ago shows the behaviour I'd expect:

1. Access https://console.cloud.google.com
2. Enter username/email
3. Get redirected to SSO page

Step 3 instead prompts for the Google ID password.

I've tried unsuccessfully using test users that aren't Super Admins to rule out anything to do with that special role.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour?

Cheers.

**Update - 11/4/2019**

Adding and enriching below comment in case anyone comes along after me with a similar issue. Hopefully I'm not alone!

I've been working with Google support to get an understanding of the behaviour to be expected for these services. There are multiple parts to this, and we're still working the last one.

Ultimately we've come to the conclusion that:

a) there is no domain specific service URL available for console.cloud.google.com (i.e. no /a/domain.com URL) - confirmed by Google Engineering team

b) organisation super admins will never be redirected to IdP for standard service URLs - not too surprising, but not well documented

c) when setting a network mask, SSO is effectively disabled for the service URL  console.cloud.google.com - still confirming this one as it seems counter-intuitive to the purpose of the network mask.

Overall the Google Support tech has advised that some of the documentation needs updating, and I'm challenging the response provided to the network mask behaviour (point c) when using a service.google.com (console.cloud.google.com in my case).
At the moment the documentation is only clear on the behaviour of network masks when using domain specific URLs (the /a/domain.com URLs).

Primary document that needs updating - https://support.google.com/a/answer/6369487

Comment: Just to get a better understanding, have you followed the steps indicated in this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en&ref_topic=6348126)

Comment: sorry @RaulBautista didn't realise there was a comment. I've been working with Google support to get an understanding of the behaviour to be expected for these services. There are multiple parts to this, and we're still working the last one. 
Ultimately we've come to the realisation that 
a) there is no domain specific service URL available for console.cloud.google.com (so no /a/domain.com URL) 
b) super admins will never be redirected to IdP for standard service URLs, and c) when setting a network mask, SSO is effectively disabled for console.cloud.google.com - still confirming this one.

Comment: Yes, I also read about the network mask but same as you I got confused, I agree with you and GSuite should update their documentation to make customer easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I wrestled with the same 3rd party IDP redirect problem as well. Because I used network masks, my users were not being redirected to our IDP when accessing Google services directly (e.g. mail.google.com). After reading your post, I stumbled upon a blurb on Google's [Network Mapping Results](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6369487) help page:

> Note:  For the network masks settings, only domain-specific service URLs, for example service.google.com/a/example.com, currently redirect to the SSO sign-in page.

Your use case may be different than mine, so this answer might not work for you. I simply wanted to test Google 3rd party IDP authentication before rolling it out to our entire org. Ergo, my use of network masks. Given the limitations as clarified in the blurb above, I opted instead to leverage Google's [Org Unit and Groups assignation for 3rd party IDP](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10723804?hl=en) functionality.

1. I used the Org Unit and Groups Assignments functionality to set the root Org Unit to **Users sign in with Google**.
2. I cleared/disabled the network mask I had set
3. I then created a separate *Test SSO* Group, assigned my test users to the Group, and specified that the Group should use the **Organization's third-party SSO profile**.

I now successfully observe the expected redirect to our 3rd party IDP when users in the *Test SSO* Group I created attempt to login to Google services directly.